# How to iterate list value in HashMap value in java?

Tags: java

I am having a map  which is having dynamic key value but for current view I have added two key with its value. I have list which which store some string.

```
Map<String , List<String>> edited = new HashMap<>();
edited.put("A" , Arrays.asList("b","f","z","s"));
edited.put("B" , Arrays.asList("a","i","u"));

List<String> ss = Arrays.asList("u","z","f","b","a","i","s");

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : edited.entrySet()) {
    for(String s : entry.getValue()){
        String.valueOf(ss.indexOf(s)+1);
    }
}
```

For each key how can I iterate map corresponding key list value and check string in list is present at which index in `ss` list like for first key `A`  its list of strings are `b,f,z,s` and `b` is present at 4 position in `ss` list similarly `f` is present at 3 same goes on final print the number in sorted order `[2,3,4,7][1,5,6]`for each list the value should be inside `[]`

final string output `[2,3,4,7][1,5,3]`

Comment: What is `RC` and what are you planning to do with the return value of `String.valueOf(RC.indexOf(s) + 1)`?

Comment: Sorry my bad during post I forget to change the variable  name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just save these indexes in a list and sort the list.

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : edited.entrySet()) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        int idx = ss.indexOf(s) + 1;
        if (idx > 0)
            indexes.add(idx);
    }
    Collections.sort(indexes);
    System.out.print(indexes);
}
```

Comment: I have tried the already but this will not print the desired output thanks anyways

Comment: The above code will print `[2, 3, 4, 7][1, 5, 6]`. Isn't it the desired output?